# c# wpf grid.SelectedCells is zero when clicking the selected cell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a SelectedCellsChanged event where I call grid.SelectedCells[0].Item. I get an exception when selecting the same cell in my datagrid(Another words click on an already selected cell). If I select a different cell the SelectedCells.Count == 1 and I have my Item.

Is this correct behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured this out. When you click again on a cell that is already selected, it is in edit mode. So this cell is apparently no longer in the selected category.